# RouterLinkActive like behavior for component not having routes

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-router

How to give router like link highlighting when the link items dont take to different route but just different operation within same component..

```
import { Component, Input, Directive, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CompactAnalystListComponent } from '../compact-analyst-list';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-compact',
  template: `
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs search-selector" role="tablist">
    <li *ngFor="let search of ordersReport"
      (click)="applyOrdering(search)">
      <a>{{ search.val }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <app-compact-research-report-list></app-compact-research-report-list>
    `
})
export class CompactComponent {

  private ordersReport = [
    { searchKey: 'uploadDate', val: 'Recent' },
    { searchKey: 'revFivedaytrend', val: 'Trending' },
    { searchKey: 'revUpside_percent', val: 'Upside' }
  ];

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    public router: Router
  ) {
  }

  applyOrdering(searchType) {
    this.authService.reportDDBS$.next(searchType.searchKey);
  }
}
```

`RouterLinkActive` behavior works out of box if each `li` takes to a separate route but in my cse it doesn't just operation of `applyOrdering()` is triggered depending on current `li` clicked.

Comment: please explain the scenario clearly and a planker would be helpful in faster understanding.

Comment: updated with full component code. note I don't have any router-outlet but only one static component `app-compact-research-report-list`

Comment: is it taking to the same component? need to be more clear on the routing side. I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add class dynamically:

```
[ngClass]="{active: (searching === search.searchKey)}"
```

or

```
[class.active]="searching === search.searchKey"
```

where `searching` is a private variable of the class to be changed inside `applyOrdering()`

Angular documentation recomends the second way

Post that you can write whatever css you like for

```
.active{
 //Whatever you wish the link to look like when active
}
```